# Shared library vs REST service. What are the pros and cons?

Tags: rest, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, system-design

There is:

- a requirement to have a key-values pairs storage shared between multiple services
- a simple table in DynamoDB
- very simple logic of key-value pairs creation

Intuitively I want to put the DynamoDB table behind a REST service that will implement all the simple logic I have. Unfortunately, this means adding a lot of reliability and performance challenges to the solution, since making my service as good, resilient, and performant as DynamoDB isn't easy.

It's been a while now that I think about creating a shared library for the purpose. The library will implement the logic and connect directly to DynamoDB table. I don't anticipate a lot of changes neither in DynamoDB table, nor in logic that will be implemented in the library.

What are the possible pros and cons of both approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that updating the shared library will not be in your control. And clients (library users) will update whenever it suits them.

If the above assumption is true, You should always go with a rest service. Considering few things

1. Your rest api may use cache instead of calling dynamodb all the time.
2. You might want to update the schema of the data you want to put in dynamodb.
3. You may use another db all together.
4. You may have some validation logic which will certainly evolve over time.

Answer (score 2):

A service is simply a packaging and deployment selection for a library.  Both are absolutely valid depending on your particular needs.

I'm curious why you feel the need to wrap dynamodb at all?  Is there some particular domain logic you would like to place on top of it to constrain it?  DynamoDB is already a restful service... Putting your own restful service on top of it *may* be advantageous, but you would have to convince me of the value of doing so.  If you have particular business logic that requires you constraining the functionality, packaging it as a shared library has certain advantages, especially if you can encapsulate that business logic and separate it from the implementation of DynamoDB.